# Show the differential solution

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I'm a little rusty on Diff Eq. I remember the basic concepts but I'm confused where the log part comes from.

Answer (score 0):

The $\log$ comes from the fact that the outlined solution method gives back $w(t)$ in part (b). But the original problem wanted the solution $w(x)$. So we reverse the substitution used in part (a) $x=e^t$ to get $t = \log x$ (this is often written as $\ln x$).

For part (a) to part (b):

Substitute $w$ into the empty space at the top of each differential operator $\left(\dfrac{d}{dx} \mathrm{\ and\ }\dfrac{d}{dt}\right)$. Then we have that

$\begin{align}
x^2\dfrac{d^2w}{dx^2}+x\dfrac{dw}{dx}+w=0
&\Longleftrightarrow \left(\dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2}-\dfrac{dw}{dt}\right)+\left(\dfrac{dw}{dt}\right)+w =0 \\
&\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{d^2w}{dt^2}+w = 0
\end{align}$

Comment: Based on your logic, how does part b satisfy that differential equation?

Comment: I was only clarifying where the $\log$ came from in the final answer given. If you fill in the details from part (a), you get part (b) almost immediately. Part (b) is then solvable using standard techniques. I'll edit in some more details if needed.

Comment: Yes, can you explicitly show part a and part b? I'm not following your logic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you. So for part c, you would just solve d^2w/dt^2 + ln(x)= 0?

Comment: No. Just solve the resulting differential equation $\frac{d^2w}{dt^2}+w=0$ as normal. The variable will be $t$ instead of $x$. Once you are done, use the substitution $t=\log x$ to get back from $t$ to $x$.